# How to create dynamic drupal 7 taxonomy views

Tags: 7, views

I have to create 1 view using taxonomy.

Let's take the example i have 8 categories: cricket, football, tennis, swimming.

I have to show this each category with their 5 latest articles.

Thew views should display database like

1. Cricket

   1. List item
   2. List item
2. Football

   1. List item
   2. List item

Like this all 8 categories with grid layout and 4 categories in row.

Right now what i am doing is creating 8 different views and showing on 1 page.

But this create issue when i am adding new category.

So it's dynamic view can help or i have to write code for this.

Comment: Try passing the top level `tid` to `views` as `argument`

Comment: If we pass top level tid(parent id), we can get only sub terms details tid, term name and term description. Is it any way to get tagged article details?

Comment: You have to use "Views arg parent term" module to pass parent term id as views argument.                      http://drupal.org/project/views_arg_parent_term

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple in Drupal 7 with the help of [EVA: Entity Views Attachment](https://drupal.org/project/eva). You are able to then create only two(2) views.

The first view will render all your categories you have in taxonomy as well as calling in the second view into a field of this view.

Your second view will then display the entities associated with the taxonomy term,
You will have to create a Term reference in your content types in order to have a field in your entity view to check against.

I have previously done this where there are categories or terms displayed with a list of entities below them, all displayed in a grid view. See Example below.

[image]